# facebook javascript SDK FB.ui send response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

i am using Facebook javascript SDK FB.ui function to send message to facebook friends. In the send dialog box that opens up upon calling FB.ui function, a friend name is there. If i remove all friend's name from "to" field of send dialog box and click "send" button, dialog box closes and i get response as 
object{ success: true }

I want to know that even thought no message is sent to any friend, why success object is returned?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an interface bug, when I remove any name from the box, I still have the button enabled. The moment the "to" field loses its focus (clikcing somewhere else), the send button gets disabled.

Comment: in my case, the send button does not get disabled when the "to" field loses focus.